# IntelliJ IDEA - track active item in Solution Explorer

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to find a nice VS feature "Track Active Item in SOlution Explorer" analog in IDEA. For those who doesn't know - when I switch between files in the main area, VS will highlight the corresponding item in Solution Explorer ("Projects" pane in IDEA).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Since 2020.1 version the option is called **Always Select Opened File**:

[image: always select]

For the previous versions:

In the **Project View** there is **Autoscroll from Source** option when you click on the "gear" icon:

[image: autoscroll from source]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! However after enabling the feature I've realised I don't need it, becomes too messy on big projects. Java unlike .NET forces a proper folder structure.

Comment: Bless you, I've been looking for this option for months, not sure how I missed it. :)

Comment: I like the new (2020) name better, but it was hard(er) to find because I was used to the pre 2020 name.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

In Rider 2020.3

Up Arrow button is Open file with single click
Down Arrow button is Always select Opened file

[image]

Comment: You legend. Thanks. Are you enjoying Rider?

Answer (score 8):

I frankly could not find required settings by all these recommendations above. I could not find how to reach this "Always select opened file".

First you need to open "show option menu":
[image]
and then "Always select opened file"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Look on left top of Rider, Right click on `File System`
- Select `Always select opened file`

Answer (score 1):

This was annoying me too and I was using the target icon in the solutions folder. I looked at these answers which were all great. but just wanted to add adiffrent path. My settings have the "new rider view" which is a simplified menu.

Anyway you can fast track to the same result but typeing "always.." in the search icon from the top menu, whcih will bring up the Always select toggle from actions. And you can switch it on from there:  as per images.  Just another way to skin that cat.

[image]

[image]